How to refer to dataset in ggplot using dplyr
I have the following dataset in R
crude_data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(19570, 19601, 19631, 19662, 
19692, 19723, 19754, 19783, 19814, 19844, 19875, 19905, 19936, 
19967, 19997, 20028, 20058, 20089, 20120, 20148, 20179, 20209, 
20240, 20270, 20301, 20332, 20362, 20393, 20423, 19570, 19601, 
19631, 19662, 19692, 19723, 19754, 19783, 19814, 19844, 19875, 
19905, 19936, 19967, 19997, 20028, 20058, 20089, 20120, 20148, 
20179, 20209, 20240, 20270, 20301, 20332, 20362, 20393, 20423
), class = "Date"), Key = c("Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)", 
"Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", 
"Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", 
"Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", 
"Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", 
"Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", 
"Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", 
"Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", 
"Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", 
"Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)", 
"Brent Price (USD)", "Brent Price (USD)"), Value = c(1.28, 0.18, 
-0.96, -0.53, -0.01, -0.2, 1.83, -0.57, -0.51, -0.13, 1.46, 0.13, 
0.48, 1.1, -0.4, 0.1, 1.75, -0.69, 2.34, 0.62, -0.75, -0.81, 
0.39, -0.8, -0.58, -0.22, -1.87, -0.86, 0.91, 86.15, 93.72, 90.6, 
82.94, 77.63, 80.12, 83.48, 85.41, 89.94, 81.75, 79, 81, 83, 
86, 86, 87, 87, 88, 88, 88, 86, 86, 86, 85, 85, 85, 83, 83, 82
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-58L))


I am trying to create a chart using ggplot, where I usually refer to my dataset within my ggplot code using a ".". Within the fill = ifelse command on the second last line of my code, I am getting an error which I believe is a result of the fact that I'm calling the dataset within my piped chain incorrectly. Any advice on how to refer to my data within the ifelse command.
crude_data %>% {
  ggplot(., aes(date, Value)) + 
    facet_wrap(~Key, nrow=2, scales = 'free_y', strip.position = 'left') +
    annotate("rect", xmin = today() - months(1), xmax = tail(.$date, 1), 
             ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "red", alpha= 0.3) +
    geom_line(data = subset(., date<=today() & Key == 'Brent Price (USD)'), linewidth = 2, col = '#6d1d26', aes(linetype='dashed')) +
    geom_line(data=subset(., date>=today() - months(1) & Key == 'Brent Price (USD)'), linewidth = 2, col = '#6d1d26', aes(linetype='solid')) 
    geom_bar(data = subset(., Key == 'Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)'), 
             fill =  ifelse(. %>% filter(Key == 'Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)') %>% select(Value) > 0, 'red', 'green'),stat='identity')
}


This is the error I get
Error in . %>% filter(Key == "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)") %>%  : 
  comparison (>) is possible only for atomic and list types


You are already subsetting for Key, so there is no need to filter on the fill =  aesthetic. You can probably just define fill = Value > 0 (untested).

general advice to help you. always do as much possible dplyr outside of and before starting to ggplot; while you technically can dplyr inside , this takes extra skill, complicates things, makes it harder to read and debug and has basically no benefit to seperating out data manipulations and plotting code.

... also, avoid mixing tidyverse functions with non-tidyverse functions. subset is from base, so doesn't understand data masking and tidy evaluation.

As others have stated, this type of code is much easier to read, and therefore debug, if you avoid dplyr() etc. inside ggplot(). This reprex dispenses with most of the filter()ing required by adding columns to crude_data. These extra columns will be called at aes().
Personally, I would create two dfs and dispense with filter() altogether, but assuming you have to use a single df:
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

# Add columns to crude_data for aes()
crude_data <- mutate(crude_data,
                     linetype = case_when(date <= today() & 
                                            Key == "Brent Price (USD)" ~ "<= Today",
                                          date >= today() - months(1) & 
                                            Key == "Brent Price (USD)" ~ ">= Today - 1 month",
                                          .default = NA),
                     fill = case_when(Key == "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)" &
                                        Value > 0 ~ "Net Gain",
                                      Key == "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)" &
                                        Value <= 0 ~ "Net Loss",
                                      .default = NA))


crude_data %>% {
  
  ggplot(., aes(date, Value)) +
    annotate("rect", 
             xmin = today() - months(1), xmax = tail(.$date, 1), 
             ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
             fill = "red", alpha = 0.3) +
    geom_line(data = filter(., Key == "Brent Price (USD)"),
              aes(linetype = linetype),
              linewidth = 2,
              colour = "#6d1d26") +
    scale_linetype_manual(name = "",
                          values = c("22", "solid")) +
    geom_bar(data = filter(., Key == "Net Inventory Withdrawls (million b/d)"),
             aes(fill = fill),
             stat = "identity") +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "",
                      values = c("#00BFC4", "#F8766D")) +
    guides(linetype = guide_legend(order = 1),
           fill = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
    facet_wrap(~Key, nrow = 2, scales = "free_y", strip.position = "left") +
    theme(legend.key.width = unit(2, "line"))
  
}


